# Как ограничить выборку по объединенному запросу?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Например, есть две таблицы: product и parameter. У одного продукта несколько параметров.

Таблица продуктов:

```
ID |   Name    |
 1 | Продукт 1 |
 2 | Продукт 2 |
 3 | Продукт 3 |
```

Таблица свойств:

```
ID | product_id |     value    |
 1 |     1      |  Параметр_1  |
 2 |     1      |  Параметр_2  |
 3 |     2      |  Параметр_3  |
 4 |     2      |  Параметр_4  |
 5 |     3      |  Параметр_1  |
 6 |     3      |  Параметр_3  |
```

Нужно вывести информацию о продуктах с параметром 1. И лимитировать это 2мя продуктами.

Например запрос такой:

```
select product.name,parameter.value from product 
join parameter on parameter.product_id=product.id and parameter.value='Параметр_1'
```

Просто дописать `limit 2` не подойдет, потому что на каждый продукт выводится по 2 строки с параметрами.

Сделал тестовые таблицы:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae76f/3/0

Как быть?

Comment: Разбейте на два запроса. Сначала получите product_id с ограничением в 2 шт, а потом используя полученные id для финишного запроса.

Comment: Но приведенный вами запрос даст по одной строке на продукт, потому что он покажет только строки с параметр_1. Или вы все таки хотите получить именно по несколько строк (столько сколько параметров у продукта) но при этом ограничится строго двумя продуктами ?

Comment: *Просто дописать limit 2 не подойдет, потому что* ... у Вас нет сортировки. Все остальные соображения - вторичны. *Нужно вывести информацию о продуктах с параметром 1. И лимитировать это 2мя продуктами.* Покажите этот желаемый Вами вывод.

Comment: @Mike, наверно, я плохо сформулировал вопрос.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae76f/3/0

Вот из такой выборки нужно выбрать только 2 первых продукта со всеми своими свойствами

Comment: @Akina http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae76f/3/0
вот, нужно выбрать только два верхних продукта со свойствами

Comment: @SokIvan Тогда что нибудь в этом роде http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae76f/4

Comment: @Mike, тут проблема в том, что если у первых двух продуктов будут другие свойства, то вообще не выведется ничего, до остальных продуктов не доберется.
Мало ли, есть какой-то limit disctinct)

Comment: @SokIvan Или вот так http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae76f/5

Answer (score 0):

Вывод первых (по id) двух продуктов имеющих параметр 'param_1' со всеми параметрами:

```
SELECT product.productName,parameter.parameterName
  from product
  join (
           select distinct product_id id
             from parameter
            where parameterName='param_1'
            order by product_id
            limit 2
  ) IDS ON product.id=IDS.id
  join parameter on product.id=parameter.product_id
 /* where parameter.parameterName in ('param_1','param_2','param_3')*/
```